# AP Computer Science A ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is the question:

Given an ArrayList of Integers of unknown size and three other int values, remove the three elements of the ArrayList located at the index positions specified by the int values. Set the first element of the ArrayList to be the average of the three removed values (rounded to the nearest int), and return the ArrayList.

Preconditions: the ArrayList will have at least four elements, and the other int values will be in decreasing order to prevent confusion about which indexes they represent.

```
apcsaListAverageRemovals([3, 6, 8, 10], 3, 2, 1) → [8]
apcsaListAverageRemovals([-177, 383, 476, -15, 62, 19, -247], 3, 2, 1) → [281, 62, 19, -247]
apcsaListAverageRemovals([258, 99, 225, 430, -497, 124], 4, 3, 3) → [19, 99, 225]
```

This was my attempted solution

```
public ArrayList<Integer> apcsaListAverageRemovals(ArrayList<Integer> lst, int a, int b, int c) {
  int suma = lst.get(a);
  lst.remove(a);
  int sumb = lst.get(b);
  lst.remove(b);
  int sumc = lst.get(c);
  lst.remove(c);
  int avg = (suma + sumb +sumc)/3;
  lst.set(0, avg);
  return lst; 
}
```

For most of the cases, my solution works, but for a few cases, it returns the first element as one less than the expected value for that case.

Heres an example: `apcsaListAverageRemovals([33, -481, 245, 359, 166], 3, 2, 2) → Expected:[257, -481]  Returned:[256, -481]`

Comment: Post the question directly, don't expect us to visit some unknown sites. And show us the actual vs expected results and an input values.

Comment: It's probable that the one less is a result of rounding. If you want to average a few integers, most of the time the result is a floating point number which you cannot represent in an Integer wrapper (effectively this amounts to a `floor`-function). Try to use `ArrayList<Float>` as a return type (even though I do not see why not just return a `float`).

Comment: Do not remove an item before get the all three items. `int avg = (lst.get(a) + lst.get(b) + lst.get(c))/3;` then remove a,b,c

Answer (score 0):

Your line that calculates the average of the 3 values doesn't round, it truncates (always rounds down). To fix this, change the line to:

```
int avg = (suma + sumb +sumc)/3 + 0.5;
```

This calculating the average as a double then adding an extra 0.5 makes it so the truncation that occurs when the double is cast to an int is also proper rounding. In case you don't see why, I'll provide a few examples, using | to represent truncation (meaning 1.5 would be written as 1|.5 because it truncates to 1).

```
2.3 should round to 2 -> 2.3 + 0.5 = 2|.8 
2.7 should round to 3 -> 2.7 + 0.5 = 3|.2
3.5 should round to 4 -> 3.5 + 0.5 = 3|.0
3.4999 should round to 3 -> 3.499 + 0.5 = 3|.999
```

And in the case of the example included in your question:

```
The average of 359, 245, and 166 should round to 257.
(359 + 245 + 166)/3.0 = 256.66666667
256.66666667 + 0.5 = 257|.16666667
```

Hope this helps!